# Phalcon doesn't load

Tags: php, nginx

I compiled Phalcon using the instructions on the site, added extension = phalcon.so to the end of my php.ini file. I restarted the server but when I run
    print_r(get_loaded_extensions());

Phalcon isn't there.

I'm using nginx on Ubuntu, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled the extension in your php.ini configuration?

```
extension = /usr/lib/php5/20090626/phalcon.so
```

That is I believe the path of where the extension will be compiled in a Ubuntu box.

Restart the server after that or in your case php_fpm :)

Comment: Thanks that worked. How did you know it would be compiled there?

Comment: The key is that you are using Ubuntu which I am too. You can always see the path of where the extension is installed at the output of the compilation process. I believe it is when issuing `sudo make install`